# Grails: Updating data in relationship

Tags: grails

I've started a little project using Grails 2.2.3 and I'm now wondering what's the right/most efficient way to update a model with relationship.

```
class Computer extends Inventory {
  String hostName
  ...
  static hasMany = [memories: Memory]
}

class Memory extends Inventory {
  Integer capacity
  String bank
  ...
  static belongsTo = [computer: Computer]
}
```

Data input is scheduled regularly from external source, no user interacts with a view.

When just doing a `mem.each { computer.addToMemories(it) }` there will be a duplicate Memory entry for each scheduled run. I can solve this be checking if a corresponding entry exists:

```
mem.each {
  if (!Memory.findWhere(it)) computer.addToMemories(it)
}
```

This would work if new mem modules are added to a computer. But imagine, modules are removed from a computer. You could create a nested loop through saved and given modules and compare them. But that's some coding and not very nice. Or you could first do a `removeAll()` and let then add all modules as new ones. But that's not very nice, too. And `id` would grow very fast.

Do you know a smarter way to handle this situation? Isn't there a possibility to say "Hey model, here is the latest set of mem modules for this computer. Add it if it's an new one, update it if has changed, or delete it if it has been removed from the computer." Or: "Update your information to this set."

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Comment: Sometimes, as software engineers, we have to write code.  Don't be afraid to do that.